# How to ensure order of outbound messages

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for advice as to the best way to solve a problem I'm having with sending messages over a socket. I need to make sure to preserve the order the messages are sent, i.e. first in first out, even when I can't guarantee that the socket is always open.

I have a network manager in my program, with a send method. This send method takes a message object and then attempts to push it out over the socket.

However, sometimes the socket will be closed, due to lost network connectivity, and I need to stop sending messages and queue up any new messages while I'm waiting for the socket to reopen. When the socket reopens, the queued messages should be sent in order.

I'm working with Javascript and Websockets. I have something like this right now, but it seems flawed:

```
function send(msg) {
    if (msg) {
        outbox.push(msg);
    }

    if (!readyState) {
        return setTimeout(send, 100);
    }

    while (outbox.length) {
        socket.send(outbox.shift());
    }
}
```

Has anyone ever tackled a problem like this before? I'm looking for a general approach to structuring the program or perhaps an algorithm that can be used.

Comment: Your ordering should be correct. Don't use `setTimeout`. Instead, bind something like `retryAll()` to the websocket's `onopen` callback and then inside the `retryAll()` function, do `while(oubox.length) { socket.send ...`

Comment: @vin that's a great answer. Add it to the list of answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adam. Here's a slightly more complete answer. If I were you, I'd wrap this up in a connection object.

```
function send(msg) {

   if (msg) {
      if (socket.readyState === socket.OPEN) {
         socket.send(msg);
      } else  {
         outbox.push(msg);
      }
   }
}


socket.onopen = function() {
   while(outbox.length) {
      socket.send(outbox.shift());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just asking in general as far as structuring?

Have you thought of using logic with push() pop() shift() and unshift()?

Essentially on a socket error callback of some sort, push() the messages into a stack. When the socket can be opened or you want to try and push the messages again, you can shift() the correct object out. You could use whatever combination of those to get the right ordering of the messages.